# New circuit and towel warmers for two bathrooms

Tags: electrical, bathroom, gfci, circuit

I am planning to add a new dedicated circuit (15A) for two hard wired towel warmers in two bathrooms, each towel warmer is 150w.

See image for my thoughts.

For the first bathroom:

- run the new circuit to the 1st bathroom to a blank face GFCI.
- from the blank face GFCI load side to a timer switch.
- from the timer switch to the hard wired towel warmer.

For the second bathroom, can I use the same circuit ?

- Run the circuit from the load side of blank face GFCI to the second bathroom.
- connect to switch and hard wired towel warmer.

Please confirm code compliance and how the wiring should run to the second bathroom.

House build year is 1994.
I am in Ontario, Canada.

Thanks.

[image: plan]

I added a second plan here based on feedback from Ed in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Not sure on Canadian laws   A 150w or 300 on a bathroom circuit is fairly minor, the putting the hardwired GFCI on a blank face is how I add jetted tubs to remodels and label it tub, I would add to existing circuit with such a small load.

Comment: Ed, thanks for your thoughts, that was my initial plan, to add the towel warmers to the original 15 amp circuit, but then i read too much internet about hair dryer loads etc...  and that original circuit reaches to 3 different bathrooms.  Which brings me to another question, can you have two wires (2black/2white) connected to the LOAD side on a GFCI?

Comment: Yes multiple wires on load. Check specs to see if screws can handle it. If not (and even if) you can pigtail.

Comment: Patrick , wow 3 bathrooms on 1ea 15 amp, that’s a lot of possibilities. The NEC limits a 20 amp circuit to 1 possibly 2 bathrooms. 
Maybe a good plan would be to pull the new circuit and move a couple receptacles to the new circuit.  I love my towel bars and except summer I leave mine on 24-7 our bath doesn't have heat. I did cycle the power at my last home it took 3-1/2 hours for nice cosy warm towels and about 2 hours to dry so I ended leaving it on most of the time.

Comment: Ed, I believe in 1994, a 15 amp circuit for 3 bathroom on one GFCI was sufficient. Nowadays with increasing wattage in hair dryer etc it's likely to trip if more than one hair dryer is running.  After reading your comments I drew a new plan and added it to the original post. I could split the original circuit in the master bath box and attach one towel warmer to each circuit. Thoughts?